# Mysql SELECT when there are multiple values for the search term

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all user_id's from the following table (excerpt) where product_id '3' is not associated with the user_id at all.

```
user_id product_id  status  terms_id
100         3           1       10
100         22          0       0
100         402         0       20
101         22          1       10
101         68          1       0
101         120         1       20
201         22          0       0
201         3           1       10
```

In this example, only user_id 101 should be selected because it doesn't have product_id 3 at all. Each user_id can have multiple entries.

I've tried the following, but it incorrectly selects all the user_id's

`SELECT distinct user_id FROM table WHERE product_id <> 3`

How could I accomplish this? The actual table has more than 3.5 million rows.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` subquery to check that the user has no associated row with `product_id = 3`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM `table` t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` t2 WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.product_id = 3)
```

Output

```
101
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nkdwXwYcdkDuLVPExAFXf4/0)

An alternate solution is to `GROUP BY user_id` and to assert that the count of rows with `product_id = 3` is 0:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM `table`
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(product_id = 3) = 0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nkdwXwYcdkDuLVPExAFXf4/1)

Comment: @AaplMike You should accept this answer. Using `distinct` is more or less like `group by`. When your query checks the row `100 22  0   0`, it is a valid result and thus adds to the resultset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would this be efficient for a query where the table has 3 million+ rows, or would I need to consider another strategy?

Comment: @AaplMike as long as you have indexes on `user_id` and `product_id` (a composite `(user_id, product_id)` will probably suffice these should work well regardless of table size. If you do happen to compare performance it'd be really interesting to hear your results.